# website loads slow when having xhr request

Tags: ajax

so I have a website which handles multiple xhr requests. The problem is when I try and open a new tab on my website. It waits for the request to finish then loads the other tab. Why is that happening?

Comment: impossible to answer with information provided. Is it synchronous?

Comment: yes it is but when i set it to false. The browser lags

Comment: You need Multi-threading calls. If its node or angular

Comment: so I need change my script?